# Show that the complex limit $\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\log z}{z-1}$ exists.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Show that the complex limit $\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\log z}{z-1}$ exists.

There is no other information given, so I am not sure what method I can use. I wanted to use L'Hopital's rule to show the limit is $1$, but is there anything I need to show before I can do this method? Possibly continuity? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: A more useful tool in complex analysis is to find the Taylor series / Laurent series.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is the derivative $(\ln z)'=1/z$, evaluated at $z=1$.  So it's $1$.